# How to customize message rules by using if condition in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to add a JQuery rule message with a condition, means for a condition x , show me `messageX` and if is y show me `messageY`.

here is my code:

```
addRuleAmount: function($element) {
        $element.rules("add", {
            ReqAmount : true, // function
            validationAmount : true, // function
            messages: {
                ReqAmount : "Required Amount !!",
                validationAmount : ($("#product_Type option:selected").attr('id') ==='car' ? "the amount must be between -100 and 100." : "the amount must be between 0 and 100.") 
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: This does not seem like a complete example. I would advise adding the condition before defining the rules.

Comment: And what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using some static associations, you may consider using an Object.

```
var messages = {
  car: "The amount must be between -100 and 100.",
  box: "The amount must be between 0 and 100.",
  wrench: "The amount must be between 0 and 1."
};
```

This gives you a more associative methodology. So you could then call it like:

```
addRuleAmount: function($element) {
  $element.rules("add", {
    ReqAmount : true, // function
    validationAmount : true, // function
    messages: {
      ReqAmount : "Required Amount !!",
      validationAmount : messages[$("#product_Type option:selected").attr("id")]
    }
  });
}
```